# Soapui - oauth2 get Access token without clicking on "get token"

Tags: oauth-2.0, soapui

How to start the oauth2 token retrieval at the beginning of the script, automatically without clicking on the "Get Token"?

Comment: I am going through the same issue right now. The only thing I have been able to find for now is this: https://www.soapui.org/oauth2/reference/oauth-2-automated-token-editor.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found the groovy script to launch the oauth2 get token:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.actions.oauth.OltuOAuth2ClientFacade

def authContainer = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.OAuth2ProfileContainer
// Get OAuth2 profile name
def profileName = context.expand("Oauth2")
def authProfile = authContainer.getProfileByName(profileName)

def clientFacade = new OltuOAuth2ClientFacade()
clientFacade.requestAccessToken(authProfile)
//To get the access token
def accessToken = authProfile.getAccessToken()
```

Comment: Or this: https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/projects/requests/auth/types/oauth2/automate/sample.html#calling-the-automated-retrieval-procedure

Comment: I edited the code I can't find the package com.eviware.soapui.support.editor.inspectors.auth.TokenType

Comment: That code worked fine for me - using ReadyAPI 2.3.0.